# Como obter o CEP completo utilizando GeocodeLocation no Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, cep, código-postal

Estou utilizando o GPS para retornar o endereço do usuário. Tudo funciona muito bem, porém o CEP retornado é no padrâo americano, com 5 dígitos. Alguém sabe alguma biblioteca ou alguma maneira de obter o padrão brasileiro de 8 dígitos ?

```
public static void getAddressFromLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude, final Context context, final Handler   handler)    
{
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;

            // String tudo[] = new String[0];
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                       // tudo[i] = address.getAddressLine(i).concat("\n");
                    }
                      sb.append(address.getAdminArea()).append("\n");
                      sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                      sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");

                    result = sb.toString();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar como está o seu código? Não consigo saber se você está usando uma API especifica, poderia informar? Grato

Comment: Não tenho muito conhecimento, mas tentou trocar `Locale.getDefault()`?

Comment: Seu aparelho está em Ingles? Provavelmente, a linha `Locale.getDefault()` está retornando outra região.